# Array.prototype.flatMap() JS is behaving strangely in test cases and a repl.it snippet, but not in browser console

Tags: javascript, jestjs, electron, chromium

My apologies if this is a rookie question, but I've stumbled upon a puzzle.

Why would a JS standard function work in the chrome browser console, but not in an electron react project jest test case, or even in a repl.it snippet? Could it be a chromium thing?

The tests were passing last time I ran them a couple of weeks ago (back in 2019)
The code affecting the tests hasn't been touched, (I'm fairly certain), but the project has been rebuilt recently.

This is the simple example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

arr1.flatMap(x => [x * 2]);
// [2, 4, 6, 8]

console.log(arr1.flatMap(x => [x * 2]));
```

If you run the above, you will see the the SO compiler is fine with it.

BUT if I access it from a jest test case for an electron react app, it kerplunks:

[image]

It works fine in the browser console:

[image]

But it does not work in a repl .it snippet:

[image]

My guess would be that it is some kind of chromium thing. But I'm not sure how to confirm that.

Could somebody please direct me to the correct resource where I could learn more about this?

Comment: What version of node.js are you testing on in your electron app / repl.it?

Comment: flatMap is at [stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-flatMap) with TC39, it's not *yet* in the standard. Depending on your Node version, it may not be available: https://node.green/#ES2019-features-Array-prototype--flat--flatMap-, although it is in many browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=flatmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because tests are using node.js version installed on your computer, just upgrade it till 12th version, in your version flatMap is not provided yet

Comment: Thanks! Yep that was it.

Comment: And thanks to jonrsharpe above for these resources:

https://node.green/#ES2019-features-Array-prototype--flat--flatMap-
 and 
https://caniuse.com/#search=flatmap

bookmarked!